# Pass by referencing not maintaining its integer value

Tags: c, parameter-passing, pass-by-reference

I am making a new question because i deemed it to be a different topic to my one about my earlier problem here: [Trouble looping through arrays define in other source files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20195482/c-trouble-looping-through-arrays-define-in-other-source-files)

The problem i current have is that i pass in a size_t value by reference to another function, i then set the value of said size_t inside that function, which i can then you in another function.

The problem i am facing is that when i pass in the size_t variable, the function that sets the value sets it's value correctly but when i return to source file where the variable is declared it has "random" values again.

Anyone have any ideas why this is happening?

system_handler.c

```
size_t ship_size;
size_t asset_size;

mayday_call* mday_ptr;
ship* ship_ptr;
rescue_asset* assets_ptr;

mday_ptr = read_mayday_file();
ship_ptr = read_ship_locations(&ship_size);
assets_ptr = read_recuse_assets(&asset_size);

printf("ships size : %d\n", ship_size);
printf("assets size : %d\n", asset_size);
```

ship.c

```
ship* read_ship_locations(size_t* size){
//no_of_lines is an unsigned int
//locof is a char array containing a file name
    no_of_lines = (count_lines(locof) -1 );
    printf("number of lines = %d \n", no_of_lines);


    size = (unsigned int)no_of_lines;
    size = no_of_lines;

}
```

rescue_assets.c

```
rescue_asset* read_rescue_assets(size_t* size) {
    //no_of_lines is an unsigned int
    //locof is a char array containing a file name
    no_of_lines = count_lines(locof);
    printf("number of lines = %d \n", no_of_lines);

    assets = calloc(no_of_lines,sizeof (rescue_asset));

    size = (unsigned int)no_of_lines;

    printf("size : %d\n", size);
}
```

Console Output:

```
please enter the file name for the ship locations data: 
ships_1.txt
number of lines = 4 
size : 4
Please enter the file name for the rescue assets data: 
rescue_assets.txt
number of lines = 37 
size : 37
ships size : 134513984
assets size : 0
```

Comment: Oops! No pass by reference in C!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As the commenter said, C doesn't support real pass-by-reference; what you have to do is pass the address of the variable instead, and use it as a pointer in the body of the function. If `size` is declared as a pointer to `size_t`, you need to refer to it that way explicitly:

```
*size = (size_t)no_of_lines;
```

instead of

```
size = (size_t)no_of_lines;
```

EDIT: Compiling with `gcc -Wall` would issue a type cast warning that would have shed some light on this problem.

Comment: +1 Turning on warnings should have helped to catch this, so you may want to add that to your answer. For example `gcc` would warn *assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast*.

Comment: @alk a cast to `size_t` would still generate a warning and not all the assignments have casts.

Comment: do i need the *size in the param as well? when i put *size in the parameter and *size in the function body the size value becomes -1bn ish. i even added the size_t cast.

Comment: The parameter declaration `size_t* size` already declares it to be a pointer. That doesn't need to be changed.

Comment: then how come when i add the suggested changes i get the value -1billion for size?

Answer (score 3):

As haccks commented: there is no pass-by-reference in C. When you pass the addresses of your `size_t`s they are just that: addresses. When you then assign `no_of_lines` to `size` in `read_ship_locations` you're changing that address **locally**. You need to dereference the address and assign to that instead:

```
*size = no_of_lines;
```

Hint: I assume you cast `no_of_lines` to `(unsigned int)` because the compiler warns about int-to-pointer conversion when you don't. When the compiler suggests a cast where you didn't intend one it's almost always *not* the solution to your problem. In this case: when you assign `no_of_lines` to `size` you're assigning an `int` to a `size_t *` and this is not a good idea since the address `no_of_lines` is most likely not a valid one.

Comment: so instead of unsigned int, should i change the return type and the variable type of no_of_lines to size_t? even when i cast it to (size_t) i get the value -1billion for size

Comment: u need to do *size = , not size =

Comment: It worked, i was using %d not %zu when printing! aha!